# Template tag if

Tags: django

I get two var:

```
post = Post.objects.get(pk=post_id)
rated = Rated.objects.filter(username=request.user,rated=True)
```

By django-mptt magic `post.comment_root.get_descendants` transformed to `node`.

In template I try use:

```
{% if node in rated %}
    X
{% else %}
    Y
{% endif %}
```

, but always get Y. Why?

P.S.: Sorry for my English

Comment: Post the sample values of "rated" and "node"

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `post.comment_root.get_descendants` nets you a queryset of `Comment`s. A `Comment` will never be in a queryset of `Rated`, because they're different types. You need to compare apples to apples.